# broken packages when install python-apt package

Tags: python, apt-get, package-managers

I want to install `python-apt` package in a debian(squeeze) server :

```
root@server:# apt-get install python-apt
```

but I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-apt : Depends: libapt-inst1.2
              Depends: libapt-pkg4.10
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I don't know how to correct this error :(

Comment: Install libapt-inst1.2 and libapt-pkg4.10 as Linux packages?

Comment: yes these are linux packages.I can't solve the dependency problem

Comment: Why can't you just install these packages with your Linux's installation tools?

Comment: when I type this : `apt-get install libapt-inst1.2` I get this error : `apt-utils : Depends: libapt-pkg4.10` and when I want to install `libapt-pkg4.10` I get this error : `E: Package 'libapt-pkg4.10' has no installation candidate`

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/419603/package-not-installing-newest-version-when-newer-version-is-available check it out!